# informatica show the latest Status based on 2 attributes

Tags: sql, database, oracle, etl, informatica

I need to show the latest Status based on 2 attributes (LAST_UPDATE and STAUS)
How can I do it in informatica? the source is flat file

Example:

```
NUMBER --------------------LAST_UPDATE ----------------- STATUS  
-----1 -----------------------01/26/2015  ----------------------   CREATED                  
-----1 ----------------------   01/27/2015  ------------------UNDER_PROCCESS                           
-----1----------------------    01/28/2015  ---------------------COMPLETED  
 -----2---------------------- 01/28/2015 ------------------ CREATED  
-----3---------------------- 01/28/2015 --------------------- UNDER_PROCCESS
```

Result should be

```
NUMBER --------------------LAST_UPDATE ------------- STATUS  ---------------LAST_STAUS  
-----1 -----------------------01/26/2015  ----------------------   CREATED -----------COMPLETED                 
-----1 ----------------------   01/27/2015  -----------------UNDER_PROCCESS ---- COMPLETED                           
-----1----------------------    01/28/2015  ---------------------COMPLETED ----------COMPLETED  
 -----2---------------------- 01/28/2015 ------------------ CREATED  ---------------- CREATED  
-----3---------------------- 01/28/2015 -------------UNDER_PROCCESS --UNDER_PROCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an Aggregator transformation or do it in an Expression transformation using variable ports.

### Using Aggregator

1. In a sorter transformation, sort on NUMBER and LAST_UPDATE, in ascending order
2. In aggregator group by on NUMBER. Optionally use the LAST function to get the latest status. By default Aggregator will output the value for last row for STATUS.
3. Use a joiner to join the output of Aggregator and Sorter.

   ```
   SQ ----> Sorter -----> Agg----> Joiner ----> Target
              |_____________________^
   ```

### Using Expression

1. Sort the data on NUMBER (ascending) and LAST_UPDATE (descending)
2. In expression transformation:

   ```
   NUMBER (i/o)
   LAST_UPDATE (i/o)
   STATUS (i/o)
   v_LAST_STATUS (v) = IIF(STATUS<>v_PREV_STATUS, STATUS,v_PREV_STATUS)
   LAST_STATUS (o) = v_LAST_STATUS
   v_PREV_STATUS (v) = STATUS
   ```

   Make sure the order of ports is correct.